# GLSL extension to support the ?: ternary operator?

Tags: opengl, glsl, ternary-operator

I'm porting WebGL GLSL shaders to OpenGL GLSL desktop using `#version 120`.

Is there any extension that would add support for the `?:` ternary operator?

like:

```
#extension GL_EXT_***: enable
```

Comment: This is clearly an XY problem. What have you done that makes you think that `?:` is *not* supported in GLSL?

Comment: it might be but #version 120 is coughing errors

Comment: That's what makes it an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/164572). Your problem is that your code is giving you errors. You *think* that the errors are due to `?:` not being supported. You should instead ask about you *real* problem: your code giving you errors.

Comment: Oh I see want you mean. I'll keep an eye open but after porting few thousands shaders, I got this errors at every instances and they all behave properly when using the same code with if / else.

Comment: After digging a bit more, you're right. Some shader does work... and some does not. That is strange indeed.

Answer (score 10):

No extension needed, it's right in the base specification:

[OpenGL Shading Language 1.20 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf), section 5.9 "Expressions", page 38, 6th bullet:

> The ternary selection operator (?:). It operates on three expressions (exp1 ? exp2 : exp3). This operator evaluates the first expression, which must result in a scalar Boolean. If the result is true, it selects to evaluate the second expression, otherwise it selects to evaluate the third expression. Only one of the second and third expressions is evaluated. The second and third expressions can be any type, as long their types match, or there is a conversion in Section 4.1.10 “Implicit Conversions” that can be applied to one of the expressions to make their types match. This resulting matching type is the type of the entire expression.